# In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following problem when using Add-Migration it sends me an error

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Labeling_Remake'.

(In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).
At first it didn't send it but I used the scaffold-dbcontext and it sent me that error. I tried to use `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Labeling_Remake.Data_Access.Sqlite.ContextSqlite` to add the context but it gives me an error

> The type 'ContextSqlite' does not inherit from DbContext. The DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextType property must be set to a type that inherits from DbContext.

I leave a sample of my context

```
namespace Labeling_Remake.Data_Access.Sqlite
{
    public class ContextSqlite: DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source = C:\Users\kevin\OneDrive\Escritorio\bat_project\Labeling_app\Labeling_Remake\Labeling_Remake\Data_Access\DbLabeling.db");
        }

        public DbSet<V_STS_ORDER> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<V_MATMAS> Skus { get; set; }
        public DbSet<V_PO_CHARACTERISTICS> V_Po_Characteristics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<V_MASTER_CHARACTERISTICS> mhfjdhksf { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I was hoping I could add the context and perform the add-migration

Answer (score 0):

Since what I needed was to create the database with the classes that I had in my context, the solution I took was to add _contextSqlite.Database.EnsureCreated(); in the constructor where I implement the context in this way when starting the program the database is created